# Powershell Replace column data

Tags: powershell

I have the following command:

```
 $WSUSClients = Get-WsusComputer | Select-Object FullDomainName, OSDescription, LastSyncResult, RequestedTargetGroupName
 $WSUSClients | ForEach-Object {$_.FullDomainName -replace ('.corp.com','')} | Set-Content 'C:\Script\WSUS Clients\WSUSclients.csv'
```

Last part it not correct I want to replace the .corp.com from the column FullDomainname and still leave the other columns but don't get this working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use a custom column:

```
$prop = @{
  name = 'FullDomainName'
  Expression = {$_.FullDomainName.replace('.corp.com','')}
}
$WSUSClients = Get-WsusComputer | Select-Object $prop, OSDescription, LastSyncResult, RequestedTargetGroupName $WSUSClients | Set-Content 'C:\Script\WSUS Clients\WSUSclients.csv'
```

Comment: `TrimEnd` argument is array of characters to trim, not string. `'Test.ccc.ooo.rrr.ppp.mmm'.TrimEnd('.corp.com')`

Comment: Thats true, didn't think about that. So sticking to `.replace` would be better. Adapted the answer